# How do I properly use NSString sizeWithFont constratinedToSize with NIAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring, nimbus-ios

I've gone over what feels like every post about this method on SO.
And a lot of the posters answers are to just put a really large value as the height constraint.

However, for me this is not working. This is my code:

```
//Create the contentLabel Label
    CGSize size = [contentText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(286, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    //Create the content label with its position 7 pixels below the title 
    contentLabel = [[NIAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                   CGRectMake(7, titleContainerView.frame.origin.y + 7, 286, size.height)];

    //Set the provided text and the font
    contentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    contentLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    contentLabel.text = contentText;
```

<strike>I am using `NIAttributedLabel`, thought this shouldn't really have an effect because the method returning what I believe to be the wrong size is part of `NSString`.</strike>

I did read in Apple's documentation that the method will truncate the string sometimes, though I thought thats what the large height constraint was for

**EDIT:**
I've discovered that it is an issue with `NIAttributedLabel`, If I use a regular UILabel it works perfectly.
Here are two source strings and corresponding screenshots, the first demonstrating my issue, the other deciding to be fine:

`"Buying a Mobile\nHello - I'd like a Motorola Defy with a Smartphone 60 Plan.\nBroadband Problem\nMy Broadband’s out. I've tested the router and cables and ruled out my equipment. Is there a problem at your end?"`

[image: Screenshot 1]

`"Buying a Mobile\nI\'m Mrs Sina Manu-Harris. My account number is 156205169. I\'m going overseas in 6 months time on the 2nd of September and I\'d like to get organized in advance and buy a new mobile phone.\nBroadband Problem\nGood afternoon. It’s Mrs Sina Manu-Harris here. My account number is 156205169. My Broadband isn’t working. I’ve checked my network and phone cables and I've also checked my filters."`

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Describe how it isn't working. A screenshot would be helpful. Did you step through to see whether the final height of the label is really the height determined in `sizeWithFont`? Maybe there are some quirks in the NIAttributedLabel implementation.

Comment: I even have the similar problem with UILabel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't depend on NSString using the same glyph placement algorithm that CoreText will. When sizing NIAttributedLabel it is recommended that you use the label's `sizeToFit` and `sizeThatFits:` methods because they use CoreText to determine the ideal size of the label.

Answer (score 1):

NimbusKit 1.0 provide a new method for calculating height of NIAttributedLabel:
NISizeOfAttributedStringConstrainedToSize()

I used to use sizeWithFont: and encounter same problem as you.
Now the new method worked for me perfectly
(I don't have any images in my attriubited label)

Answer (score 0):

Please check with string @"T\nT\nT", it will only prints @"T\nT\n". It seems _textFrame only shows two visible lines instead of three.